In AWS CloudWatch Logs Insights how can I use the equivalent of SQL subqueries?
Some requests are giving errors, and I want to get better insights into which ones / why.  To do this I want to get additional information from the same log stream, but other entries - effectively matching between the "error" entry, and the "info" entry on request Id.
For example, with these log entries:
(aaaa9999-c111-4a1b-a1b6-3988faaabbbc) requestType=1
(aaaa9999-c111-4a1b-a1b6-3988faaabbbc) irrelevant log line - please discard
(aaaa9999-c111-4a1b-a1b6-3988faaabbbc) Bad response format error
(aaaa8888-c111-4a1b-a1b6-3988faaabbbc) requestType=2
(aaaa8888-c111-4a1b-a1b6-3988faaabbbc) irrelevant log line - please discard
(aaaa7777-c111-4a1b-a1b6-3988faaabbbc) requestType=3
(aaaa7777-c111-4a1b-a1b6-3988faaabbbc) irrelevant log line - please discard
(aaaa7777-c111-4a1b-a1b6-3988faaabbbc) Bad response format error
...
my ideal output format would be:
(aaaa9999-c111-4a1b-a1b6-3988faaabbbc) requestType=1
(aaaa7777-c111-4a1b-a1b6-3988faaabbbc) requestType=3
This feels like an SQL subquery, and something I know I could do in SQL, but from what I've understood of the CloudWatch Logs Insights ecosystem and syntax, I can't see a way of doing it.
But surely this is something that would be useful, and ought to be possible?! I assume it's more likely I've missed a trick, than AWS has; I haven't been able to find the solution yet on SO.
I tried this
parse @message /^(?<reqid>.*) Bad response format error$/
|filter (strcontains(@message, reqid) and @message like /requestType/)
but this just results in those lines containing the error message.  It seems the "parse" command effectively just adds a new reqid field to each log record, then the filter command compares the reqid in each record with the message in that record.
I also tried this
parse @message /^(?<reqid>.*) Bad response format error$/
| filter (isPresent(reqid) and (@message like /(?<reqid>) /) and (@message like /requestType=/)) 
| display reqid, @message
Instead I need something that in SQL would look something like this:
SELECT * from logMessages
WHERE message LIKE '%requestType%'
AND reqId IN (
    SELECT reqId from logMessages WHERE message LIKE '%Bad response format error/
)
